# Update parent array from children arrays values on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, onclick

Hi I am trying to make a simple single page where the user gets random images from unsplash, they then type in their email (which gets added to array 1), then they select the pictures they want to assign to their email (array 2), then when you hit submit, the parent array (array 3) gets updated with the details from array 1, array 2?

Rather then giving snippets of code I have uploaded to JSFiddle so you can see the whole picture.

Here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/Coxy/y9705ash/

Here is the bit I am having trouble with :

```
    var user_selection = ['user_email', 'user_images'];

var user_email = [];
$('.submit').on('click', function(e) {
    user_email.push($('this').data('input'));
});

var user_images = [  ];
    $('.gallery-item').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        user_images.push( $('this').data('') );                
   });
   console.log(user_selection)
```

Any suggestions or direction would be much appreciated.

To be a bit clearer, wen you hit the confirm button, the email address gets added to the user_email array.

When you click an image, the image gets added to the user_image array.

When you click the submit button, the user_selection array is updated with the details of the first 2 arrays ready to submit in an email.

Here is an update of the code, still not working properly:

```
 var user_selection = [];

var user_email = $("[user_email^='.email[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();
}).get();

var user_images = $("[user_images^='.gallery-item[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();
}).get();

$('.btn-submit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    user_email.push($(this).val);
});

$('.gallery-item').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    user_images.push($(this).val);                
});
   console.log(user_selection); 

   //simulate click
   setTimeout(() => combineArray(), 1000);
   
   function combineArray() {
     user_selection.push(user_email);
     user_selection.push(user_images);
     console.log(user_selection);
   }

   $('.submit').on('click', function(e) { 
       e.preventDefault();
       combineArray();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining your user_selection with just strings. Try to add it to the end. Check my example.

```
var user_email = [];
....
var user_images= [];
....
var user_selection = [user_email, user_images];
```

```js
    let array1 = [{email: 'test@test.com'}];
    let array2 = ["picture 1", "picture 2", "picture 3"];

    let combinedArray = [];

    //simulate click
    setTimeout(() => combineArray(), 1000);
    
    function combineArray() {
      combinedArray.push(array1);
      combinedArray.push(array2);
      console.log(combinedArray);

      //or without push
      combinedArray = [array1, array2];
      console.log(combinedArray);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, do you mean like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/Coxy/y9705ash/2/

Comment: just combine them in your submit button function.

 $('.submit').on('click', function(e) {
        user_email.push($('this').data('input'));
        //combine your filled arrays here
            
    }); But I have tried it out and it seems the array is not getting filled. Do not have further time for investigating but I think you can do this :)

Comment: Thank you nosTa! You have been a big help, I will give it a go and keep you updated! Thank you again!  :)

Comment: if you need more support just let me know. Maybe I can help later.